# getting state from object in Link to param

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

According to docs for `react-router-dom` , I can pass in state from `Link` to the component like so:

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/signin",
    state: { role: 'employee' } }}
  }}
/>
```

However I'm having trouble picking it up from a functionally declared React component:

```
const SignIn = props => {
...
  return ( {console.log(props} )
```

Looking in console, I see `undefined`. What simple thing am I missing here?

Using react-router-dom version 5.0.0, react version 16.8.6

Comment: I think you have to add `withRouter` to your `SignIn` component, then access `props.location.state` or `props.location.role` - not exactly sure which one. A sample codesandbox would help

Comment: So for a class-based component you are receiving the correct props?

Comment: That seems kind of like how I remember using link state, how are you rendering `SignIn` ? Is that the component you're exporting and is presumably being passed to a route somewhere like `<Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />` ?